# Loop syntax error in MySQL cursor

Tags: mysql, loops, cursor

I have been trying to use a cursor and following a tutorial I found online, I was able to come up with the following cursor.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE customers_with_oldest_version (INOUT customerCount varchar(4000))
BEGIN

DEClARE customers_with_oldest_version CURSOR FOR
select * from CustomerSoftware where software in (select min(minimumSoftware) from ProductSoftware);

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
FOR NOT FOUND SET @finished = 1;

set @row_entry = "";

open customers_with_oldest_version;

get_customers: LOOP

FETCH customers_with_oldest_version INTO @row_entry;

IF @finished = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE get_customers;
 END IF;

SET @customerCount = @customerCount + 1;

END LOOP;

CLOSE customers_with_oldest_version;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

But I am unable to create this procedure, since phpmyadmin is giving me an error saying that 
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@row_entry; IF @finished = 1 THEN LEAVE get_customers; END IF; SET @c' at line 16`

What am I missing here?

Comment: You never use `@row_entry`. Why are you fetching into it?

Comment: @Barmar I am planning to use it later. I just wanted to see what causes this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fetch into a user-defined variable. This is a bug that has been around for many years, see https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2261

Declare a regular local variable for it.